# file_put_contents() not over writing, just appending

Tags: php

I have a simple `file.txt` which needs to be over written every time I run a certain php code.

```
$msg ="string";
$file = 'file.txt';
$opn = file_get_contents($file);
$opn .= $msg;
file_put_contents($file, $opn);
```

The code works perfectly, It added the string I want it to add, but It is appending it to the former. I want it to erase it blank and then write.

I've read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php 
I am not using the `FILE_APPEND` argument either.

It's a simple thing that I'm not seeing. Help me out.

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole code. I'm getting some data from a site. The data is in this format `12.222 AAA` and I am trying to save that to a text file to easily access later.
But for some reason something does not work. The scraper works perfectly, and the `file_put_contents()` woks perfectly if I set the `$item="string";` but it does not work when when `$item` is set to equal the code below. If I echo $item I get what I want.

```
<?php 

include('simple_html_dom.php');


$html = file_get_html('http://site.com/boom');

// find the thing in the span
foreach($html->find('div') as $article) {
    $item = $article->find('span', 0)->plaintext;

echo $item;

    $file = 'file.txt';
    $fh = fopen( 'file.txt', 'w' );
    fclose($fh);
    $opn = file_get_contents($file);
    $opn .= $item;
    file_put_contents($file, $opn);

}
?>
```

Comment: Remove the period on the fourth line. It's the quickest solution but certainly not the best if Gaurav's solution didn't work (I assume there's code that you aren't showing us).

Answer (score 4):

you are concatenating the string in `$opn .= $msg;`

You can use

```
$msg ="string";
$file = 'file.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $msg);
```

No need to read the data.

Comment: I did and now it's not writing to it. The reason I did that is because of this http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php (Example 1)

Comment: in case if you have copied my answer, there was a error. I have used $opn instead of $msg

Comment: It's not even adding anything. What is your file permission/chmod number?

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was in my part with some other setting

Comment: you should post your answer, so that other can get help from it.

Comment: actually I have not solved it, I'm working on it. Check my edit, I put more information. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the contents of the file into a string variable ($opn), appending your message ($msg) to $opn, then writing $opn back to file.... the append you're doing is

```
$opn .= $msg;
```

If you want to write only $msg to the file, then use

```
file_put_contents($file, $msg);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was in my part with some other setting

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $msg ="string";
    $file = 'file.txt';
    $fh = fopen( 'file.txt', 'w' );
    fclose($fh);
    $opn = file_get_contents($file);
    $opn .= $msg;
    file_put_contents($file, $opn);
    ?>
```

This code will do what you are looking for..:)

Comment: Thanks Rajat, but I want it to overwrite whatever is in the txt file and only have one "string". Basically everytime the code runs there should only be one instance of the "string". Your code is just appending to it.

Comment: Did you try to run it???its not appending..it will erase all previous content and write your msg variable there..

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was in my part with some other setting

Answer (score -3):

> file_put_contents($file, $opn,FILE_APPEND);

Comment: In the future, please write out why an answer is a correct answer. The additional effort to explain may help future users searching for not only an answer, but the correct answer for their situation.